# What is the origin of the phrase signal improvement?

Tags: phrases, phrase-origin

I have checked all the websites that collect info on phrase origins and none of them had anything to say about the expression signal improvement. Sending signals by semaphore and fires like in the Great Wall of China are very old so it could have its origins in that activity. My understanding of the meaning of the expression is that a signal improvement is an improvement that is really significant and stands out from all the rest. I have tried to find a definition but, again, no luck. The expression exists back to 1800 on Google NGram.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the phrase "signal improvement" is some kind of idiom that means something other than what the words themselves convey? If so, I've never heard that. I've never heard "signal improvement" used as any kind of expression that would convey anything other than a signal improving. To be sure, I Googled it, and I don't see those words coming together any differently than any other noun and modifier or to mean anything different than what they literally mean.  You need to provide some research, research that includes citations of actual use in context.

Answer (score 2):

The sense lies in the word **signal**:   [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/179519?rskey=Yqd9ag&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> - Notable, conspicuous; remarkable, striking.
> - a. Of an event, action, or quality.

As in:

> 2000   N.Y. Times Bk. Rev. 23 Jan.    This gathering of data is a
>   signal achievement.

The OED find this early usage:

> **1591**   G. B. A. F. tr. Discouery Subtiltie & Wisedome Italians xxxvii. 57   Now what nation hath that been..which hath done God so
>   signall a peece of seruice. Surely it was England.

My sense is that there is no idiomatic **phrase** as 'signal improvement'.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=signal) reports:

> "remarkable, striking, notable" ("serving as a sign"), **1640s**.

Comment: Thanks much. I see I should have put my focus on the use of signal as an adjective. I did some looking on the web but I do not have an OED subscription. There was virtually no information on the adjectival use of signal other than "adjective early 17th cent.: from French signalé, from the Italian past participle segnalato ‘distinguished, made illustrious’, from segnale ‘a signal’." Again, thanks for steering me in the right direction.